# Title header is stuck up in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm totally new to HTML/CSS and trying to design a website as seen below. 
As you can see in the photo below, the main title is squished up into the nav bar.

What is the best practice for repositioning the title in this situation? I'm thinking that I can use `position: relative` to move it down slightly, but I'm wondering if there is a more optimal way to fix this issue. I've posted my HTML and CSS code below the image if needed.

[image: photo]

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SuperMegaAwesome Landing Page | Matt Bell</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Stylesheets/CSS/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Stylesheets/CSS/normalize.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <section id="banner">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <header>
                    <p id="logo">Super<span>Mega</span>Awesome</p>

                    <nav>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                        <a href="#">Get in touch</a>
                    </nav>
                </header>

                <div id="content">
                    <h1 class="title">We create beautiful products</h1>
                    <h2 class="sub_title">Truffaut DIY keffiyeh, twee messenger bag venmo locavore organic master cleanse marfa gochujang selvage</h2>
                    <div class="button_wrapper">
                        <a href="#" class="button button_highlight">Learn More</a>
                        <a href="#" class="button button_secondary">Play Video</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
  font-family: "Brandon Grotesque", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1440px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#banner {
  background-image: url(../../images/banner_background.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#banner header {
  padding: 2rem, 0;
}
#banner #logo {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.35rem;
  float: left;
  clear: right;
}
#banner #logo span {
  font-weight: 400;
}
#banner nav {
  float: right;
}
#banner nav a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
#banner .wrapper {
  padding: 2rem 0 6rem 0;
}
#banner .wrapper .title, #banner .wrapper .sub_title {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}
#banner .wrapper .title {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  margin: 0;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

Comment: I think that since your `<header>` contains only 2 floated elements you need `#content` to `clear: both;` or use a clearfix style on the header. (i.e. `.clearfix:after { content: ''; display: block; clear: both; }` then add that class to the header)

Comment: If the banner is a `position: fixed` element, then you'll need to make the content below that (perhaps a wrapping container) `position: absolute` with a `top: insert-banner-height-here`. I don't see a `position` property anywhere in the `CSS` is there any `CSS` left out? A typical flow would push the next element down below since your `width` is set to `90%`.

Comment: @zgood Thank you! I used `#content` to `clear: both;` and that worked.